# Indexing Mysql Group BY Query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I Have a table called train_stop which have ~1 million rows.

I have following query-

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM train_stop where code='XYZ' AND active=1 UNION SELECT * FROM train_stop where code='ABC' UNION SELECT * FROM train_stop where code='STU'...... ) AS t3 GROUP BY t3.number order by departs
```

This query uses only same table `train_stop`. First i select certain rows based upon `code` and then group it by `number`. I have tried indexing different columns but above query always uses `using temporary, using filesort`. Execution time is of the order of seconds. Please tell if there could be better way to write above query and indexing strategy so as to optimize and get results in milliseconds. Your help would be much useful.

```
Create Statement is `CREATE TABLE `train_stop` (
  `number` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `stop_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `station name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `arrives` time NOT NULL,
  `departs` time NOT NULL,
  `halt` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `pf` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `km` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `speed` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `elev` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  KEY `index_1` (`number`(767),`code`(767)),
  KEY `PIndex` (`number`(767),`stop_number`),
  KEY `three_columns_idx` (`code`(767),`active`,`departs`),
  KEY `two_columns_idx` (`code`(767),`active`),
  KEY `two_columns_group_idx` (`number`(767),`departs`),
  KEY `one_columns_group_idx` (`departs`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`
```

Comment: so could you post your `CREATE TABLE` statement query? and what is your server MySQL or MS SQL? you have to select just one and tag it

Comment: just investigate your query a little. What are you doing here??? why do you `UNION` table itself many times???? and why do you post just part of your query? if you need help you should post full query.

Comment: who did create this table structure??? why `\`number\` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,`?? do you know what does it mean? `varchar(1000)` is a huge key!!! who need that?

Comment: there are certain string which have longer length. So i have used varchar(1000) . Now if i write this query in this fashion as explained by Mahmoud. Code='XYZ' OR code='ABC' ...now both XYZ and ABC exist, but i want only first selector that is XYZ to appear in result. But my observations are with this query it randomly select XYZ OR ABC.

Comment: To analyze the query try `explain select...` and then share the result into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query traverse whole table one time for each subquery and this is your bottleneck. please try this one

```
SELECT * FROM train_stop where (code='XYZ' AND active=1) OR (code='ABC') OR (code='STU') ...
Group by number order by departs
```

and with regard to your query which uses `GROUP BY` statement, I think you cannot write `select *` please narrow the selection phrase!!!

Comment: Hi , Tried your query. It is fast but it fails my purpose. Look, i want the first where selector to appear in result if multiple where selectors are matched.e.g. Code='XYZ' OR code='ABC' ...now both XYZ and ABC exist, but i want only first selector that is XYZ to appear in result. But my observations are with this query it randomly select XYZ OR ABC.

Answer (score 0):

remove the union and use OR. for some reason if the order by and group by are together it will not get the rows that you are expecting. instead order it first inside the sub query and group by at the end of the query

something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM train_stop where (code='XYZ' AND active=1)
OR (code='ABC') OR (code='STU') ... ORDER BY departs ASC) AS t3 GROUP BY 
t3.number
```

decide if you want the order of departs by ascending or descending