# SQL Query multiple where clause prioritize

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM train_stop where code='ABC' OR code='XYZ' OR code='DEF' group by number order by departs
```

Now since i am using `Group By` so as to take only one row with specific number. But i want to prioritize the result. It means if my table has code='ABC' and code='XYZ' , then the result must select `ABC` row and not 'XYZ' because ABC has come first in where clause.  Similarly if table has `XYZ` and `DEF` for same number, `XYZ` must come up in result and not `DEF`. Till now my experiments led me that its hows on random basis. I would be helpful if you could guide me to achieve this and proper indexing strategy for this case. Thanks.

The create statement is as follows-

```
Create Statement is `CREATE TABLE `train_stop` (
  `number` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `stop_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `station name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `arrives` time NOT NULL,
  `departs` time NOT NULL,
  `halt` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `pf` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `km` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `speed` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `elev` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  KEY `index_1` (`number`(767),`code`(767)),
  KEY `PIndex` (`number`(767),`stop_number`),
  KEY `three_columns_idx` (`code`(767),`active`,`departs`),
  KEY `two_columns_idx` (`code`(767),`active`),
  KEY `two_columns_group_idx` (`number`(767),`departs`),
  KEY `one_columns_group_idx` (`departs`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`
```

Comment: `select * ... group by ...` is never a good idea. NONE of the values other than those present in the `group by`, or used in aggregate functions are guaranteed

Comment: what is the difference between this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933229/indexing-mysql-group-by-query? If you did not get an answer, try updating/improving your question rather than posting it again.

Comment: at a glance, the question seems to be about completely different things. that one was about performance, this one is about abusing group by

Comment: This is a different version of that question but its different. Now please help me with my problem. My concerns are prioritizing conditions in where clause.

Comment: "ABC has come first in where clause" that's not how sql works

Comment: So, you want to select the row containing 'ABC', if not found, select 'XYZ', if not found, 'DEF'? Is this what you mean by prioritize? Or do you mean just sorting?

Comment: i think you're right in your first theory

Comment: @Uooo Exactly! Please help

Comment: Is it `mysql` or `sql-server`? They're not the same.

Comment: Its Mysql and not sql-server. Rectified.

Comment: Could you atleast provide some sample data? A fiddle would help.

Comment: You *really* should have a PRIMARY KEY in there...

Comment: also, most of those fields are FAR larger than they need to be. 1000 characters to represent a speed?

Answer (score 3):

Group by is the wrong way to do this. This will do it.  You would need to change the `order by` portion to match your `where` clause ordering whenever you change the codes to check against.

```
select * from (
  select if(@prev = number, @rank := @rank + 1, @rank := 1 and @prev := number) rank, 
         train_stop.*
    from train_stop, (select @prev := 0, @rank := 1) q  
  where code = 'abc' 
    or code = 'xyz' 
    or code = 'def' 
  order by number asc, code='abc' desc, code='xyz' desc, code='abc' desc
) q where rank = 1;
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccc4d/7

This query assigns a rank per ordered group, and then selects just the top ranked value out of each group. Would probably break if you have a station number 0

Comment: Hi pala_ It works perfect as per requirement. Can you please suggest how should indexing be done for this query.  for me it looks like 
Create index on 'train_stop' `idx_3` ('code','number')

Comment: `(code,number)` should be sufficient, however it might not be doable with fields that large, in which case just `code`. either way, you might want to revisit the need for 1000 characters in each of those fields - it seems excessive.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I am filtering odd entries in number so as to make it 15 characters.

Comment: another recommendation would be, if they are actually numbers only, and not numbers that contain characters, change them to numeric fields

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM train_stop 
where code='ABC' 
 OR ( code != 'ABC'
  and code = 'XYZ' )
 OR ( code != 'ABC'
  and code != 'XYZ'
  and code='DEF' )
group by number
order by departs
```

Comment: this is identical to the first query.  `where` is evaluated before `group`, so it's only evaluating one row at a time. if this works, it's just coincidence. test here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccc4d/1 to see it failing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM train_stop where code='ABC' OR code='XYZ' OR 
code='DEF' order by departs ASC) as t group by t.number
```

Comment: No. this isn't the answer. it suffers from the same group by abuse as the original question, and does NOT give correct answers unless it is by _accident_. It is also not the same question. The one you've linked is about performance, this one is about getting specific results.

Comment: ok, if that's what you said. but try the edited answer above and up vote me if that is work.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to work, read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html the whole point is that you cant expect `group by` to magically choose the values you want for fields that aren't either aggregated, or present in the `group by`

Comment: Because it did it right 100 times in a row does not guarantee some edge case on the server won't cause the wrong result the 101st time.  As pala_ cited, the documentation *specifically* states this scenario and that there are no guarantees.