# How to get one user's rank from mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have like this table at my mysql db for highscore.

[image]

and I got SQL for get rank of all users.

```
SELECT b.id
 , b.name
 , @rank_cnt := IF(@prev_score = b.score,@rank_cnt,@rank_cnt+1) AS rank
 , @prev_score := b.score AS score
    FROM BBR b
       CROSS
        JOIN ( SELECT @rank_cnt := 0, @prev_score := NULL) i
       ORDER BY b.score DESC, b.id DESC
```

if I run above SQL, I get following result,

[image]

But I want to know from here, specific user's rank info only.

If I wrote `WHERE name = 'sim' before ORDER BY`, his rank become 1.
I expect here '4' as result.

How should I revise?

Thanks much.

Comment: You need to use a subquery, so that you are doing all the ranking before the filtering. e.g. `SELECT id, name, rank, score FROM (<your current query>) AS t WHERE t.Name = 'SIM'` - as it stands you are filtering first, so you are only applying the ranking to one row, hence you get the rank of 1.

Comment: Do you have more than one row per user?

Comment: More conventional ranking would be 1 1 3 3 5 6 7 (e.g. after two people are tied for first, next is 3rd, not 2nd).  Does that make sense or you need it like this?

Comment: @steveklein Yes it seems make sense, but how to do that by SQL?

Comment: there is an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934371/sql-query-multiple-where-clause-prioritize/29934593#29934593) that has per group ranking (ie, per score in this instance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET @rank_cnt := 0;
SET @prev_score := NULL;
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT b.id
    , b.name
    , @rank_cnt := IF(@prev_score = b.score,@rank_cnt,@rank_cnt+1) AS rank
    , @prev_score := b.score AS score
   FROM BBR b
   ORDER BY b.score DESC, b.id DESC
) AS subQ
WHERE subQ.name = "sim";
```

If you are using the same connection, you shouldn't need that bogus "JOIN" to initialize your session variables.

Comment: Thanks! Solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query,

`select name
       ,Find_in_set(score, (select group_concat(distinct score order by score desc) from BBR)) rank 
from BBR 
where name='sim';`